# JetBrains IntelliJ Idea taking very long time to "make"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For some reason IntelliJ seems to be having an issue where it takes minutes to compile a simple Java program. Here is a picture of it taking 1 minute and 54 seconds to compile the most basic "Hello World" program:

[image]

That was taken compiling using java 8. I tried again using java 7 and here's a screen shot of that attempt:

[image]

It took 3 minutes 42 seconds. This is not only happening the very first time; it is happening every time I compile, even the second or third time compiling it. If I was to compile it by clicking "Make Project" then click "run" it would remake the project, taking another 2minutes just to run it... This is becoming a serious issue and any help is greatly appreciated.

### Edit:

I'm running Windows 8 on an Intel i7.

### SOLVED:

For anyone else having this problem... Check if you have MalwareBytes: Anti-Exploit installed. For me it severely impacted the performance of any of the IDE's I tried to code Java in, and was the ultimate cause of this issue. :)

Thanks,
Sean.

Comment: Is this an IntelliJ specific problem? Have you tried building your project with something like Ant/Maven or another IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: @ChristianWilkie Yes, and it was affected as well. Turns out the problem was MalwareBytes Anti-Exploit Free.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem... Check if you have MalwareBytes: Anti-Exploit installed. For me it severely impacted the performance of any of the IDE's I tried to code Java in, and was the ultimate cause of this issue. :)

Comment: I see, glad to hear you solved your issue. You may want to post your solution as an "answer" to your problem and accept that as the solution.

Comment: Incredible, I thought McFee was slow, but this...

Comment: Please create an answer to your question and remove the answer from the question, this isn't a forum. The title shouldn't include that it is solved, please read [answer].

Answer (score 2):

Bang.. I was going to suggest the same. *Always prefer to exclude the build directory from your anti-virus scan*. Had the same issue for quite some time with McAfee installed on my system... but eventually realized that it was scanning for new files which were created post build process.